# Could not load file or assembly Xamarin.iOS or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on a xamarin proyect where I need to open a pdf. For android I need to use Radaee and for iOS the native reader. Right now I'm with the android side of things since the iOS is already done. When I load the app and try to open a pdf I get

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies.'
```

I've tried to add the Xamarin.iOS to the dependecies of the shared proyect and the Android proyect but none seem to work, I tried to clean and rebuilt in multiple ocassions with no effect.

The radee code is as simple as:

```
string localDocUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, uri);

 //If Android.
 if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                RadaeePDFManager radaee = new RadaeePDFManager();
                Context cont = Android.App.Application.Context;
                radaee.Show(cont, localDocUrl, "");
            }
```

I'm working on visual studio 2022 if it's relevant.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/?force_isolation=true#setup-and-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the `NSBundle.MainBundle` is the Api of the Xamarin.iOS, you can't add the reference of Xamarin.iOS into the Android part and also can't call the method of the xamarin.ios on the Android platform.

So you can try to use the [Dependency Scrvice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call the platform native code in the platform part not in the share project.

And you can also migrate you project to the maui. Maui supports you call the platform native code in the share project when you used `#if`. For more information you can refer to the official document about [invoke platform code in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: Thanks for that i forgot about NSBundle beeing only iOS, I moved it down inside the "else if (device == ios)" and now i have nothing on top of it, i've commented the radaee code just to check one vlue before working on it on the debug but it is still breaking even if the NSBundle isn't accesed by the android part.

Comment: The debug output adds `[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.iOS.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.iOS.dll
**System.IO.FileNotFoundException:** 'Loading...'`

Comment: No, even though you used the `else if (device == ios)`, you can't add the xamarin.ios native code in the share project. When you run on the andorid, the code in the `else if (device == ios)` will still be compiled on android. You need to used the Dependency Service to call the native code in the xamarin forms. @Lorem

Comment: Thank you very much, I moved all the problematic code (wich turned out t be more than I though [I'm very new to the xamarin thing]) into dependencies servicies and now it works.